# Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

run the my project

```
ng build --prod --base-href="./"
```

getting below error message

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng-multiselect-dropdown/fesm2015/ng-multiselect-dropdown.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:265:35)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:77:21)
    at visitNodes (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16514:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16740:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16635:21)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16703:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16692:24)
    at checkNodeForDecorators (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/transforms/scrub-file.js:68:31)
    at visitNode (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16505:24)
    at Object.forEachChild (/home/gayathri/Desktop/webapp8/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:16599:21)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined at getAssignmentTargetKind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53827570/typeerror-cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-at-getassignmenttargetkind)

Comment: do you solve this problem. I m having the same issue, when  i m trying to build newly created library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined while publish angular+.net core project in CI-CD azure devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626776/cannot-read-property-kind-of-undefined-while-publish-angular-net-core-project)

Answer (score 7):

Not a permanent solution, but I was getting this in production only with datepicker. I went to the production configuration in angular.json and changed buildOptimizer to false.

Comment: helped but trying to understand or find a permanent solution..! thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I found it really hard to find information about this error for library builders, so I'm posting it here. We can't just tell the users to upgrade their Angular's versions or disable build optimization.

For a library to work well with versions 6 and 7 of @angular/cli, you must export all decorators metadata when building the library. To do that, add the following to the `tsconfig.json` of your lib:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding your answer - from a fellow library developer this was a massive help to me

Comment: When I checked tsconfig.json, emitDecoratorMetadata was already set to true but I was still facing this issue.

Comment: @AdnanSheikh Are you sure you're checking the tsconfig of your lib and not the tsconfig of the project using your lib? If you are, check if Angular is using the tsconfig.json, sometimes it uses another file like tsconfig.prod.json, in this case, be sure to alter the file Angular is using.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the version of *ng-multiselect-dropdown to  0.2.3* might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the caret ^ symbol from the package i.e.

```
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.3" to "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "0.2.3"
```

Resolved my issue.